# If M is a non-compact manifold, then Diff(M) is not a manifold. Yet it still has manifold-like properties. What is it?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, diffeomorphism

If $M$ is a non-compact smooth manifold, then $\text{Diff}(M)$ is not locally compact and hence not a manifold. Yet it still has manifold-like properties. In fact it has Lie group-like properties. It's "smooth" and a group. Yet it seems to be so big that not even a infinite-dimensional Lie group can capture its essence. What is it exactly?

Comment: Noncompactness of the manifold is irrelevant here. It's a long story. As for a partial answer with references see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391509/lie-algebra-of-a-diffeomorphism-group?rq=1).